# While Iterator in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, request

I'm trying to create a loop to read, for example, 4200 users from 1000 to 1000 but I can't get it to cut when it reaches the end. I tried it with if, for and I couldn't do it.

I have programmed in JAVA but with Groovy I see that the structure is different.

```
urlUsers = urlUsers.concat("/1/1000");        
List<UserConnectorObject> usersList = null;

while({    

gesdenResponse = GesdenUtils.sendHttpRequest(urlUsers, "LOOKUP", null,
request.getMetaData()?.getLogin(), request.getMetaData()?.getPassword());

log.info("Users data in JSON: "+gesdenResponse.getOutput())

usersList = GesdenUtils.fromJSON(gesdenResponse.getOutput(), GesdenConstants.USER_IDENTITY_KEY);

usersList.size() == 10;
log.info("List size in JSON "+usersList.size());
}()) continue
```

Comment: This looks quite confused. You seem to have the main body of your loop in the condition, and the actual body of the loop is just 'continue'. A while loop should look like 'while (condition) { body }'; the body of the loop keeps repeating as long as 'condition' evaluates to 'true'. What's the actual condition that should cause the loop to stop?

Comment: @ChrisLong The condition to stop the loop is that it does not find users but the loops have to read from 1000 to 1000 users

Answer (score 1):

Groovy has lots of [loop structures](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_looping_structures), but it is crucial to separate the regular ones (lang built-ins) and the api functions which take [closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) as *an argument*

#### take closure - no plain way to escape

If you want to iterate from A to B users, you can use, for instance,

```
(10..20).each { userNo ->   // Here you will have all 10 iterations
    if ( userNo == 5) {
       return
    }
}
```

If something outrageous happens in the loop body and you cannot use *return* to escape, as loop boddy is a closure (separate function) and this *resurn* just exits this closure. Next iteration will happen just after.

#### use regular lang built-in loop structures  - make use of *break/continue*

```
for (int userNo in 1..10) { // Here you will have only 5 iterations
   if (userNo == 5) {
       break
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your closure always return falsy because there is no explicit `return`, and the last statement evaluated is the call to `log.info(String)` which returns `void`.

Use an explicit `return` or move/delete the log statement.